# Installing SOUNDEX for SQLite with Homebrew

Tags: sqlite, homebrew

I'm trying to use the SOUNDEX function with SQLite.  Can I install this with homebrew, or do I need to compile from source?

I've tried

`brew install --fresh sqlite --with-functions`

which seems to install extension functions, but I still get `Error: no such function: SOUNDEX` messages on my queries.

I also tried to modify the `sqlite` formula, adding the following compile option

`ENV.append 'CPPFLAGS', "-DSQLITE_SOUNDEX"`

based on http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html, but this still fails.

Ideally I'd like to avoid compiling SQLite manually from source, even if that means I need to write a custom homebrew formula.

Comment: YOu can check with [`PRAGMA compile_options`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_compile_options) whether compilation with `SQLITE_SOUNDEX` worked.

Answer (score 0):

That's the right flag, but you might not be running the right sqlite.

Your approach is correct. Adding that `ENV.append 'CPPFLAGS', "-DSQLITE_SOUNDEX"` will compile it with soundex. I just tested it with SQLite 3.7.16.2 and homebrew on my OS X 10.8.3 system. Or, for more control, like this.

```
  option 'with-soundex', 'Enable the SOUNDEX function'

  def install
    [ ... ]
    ENV.append 'CPPFLAGS', "-DSQLITE_SOUNDEX" if build.include? "with-soundex"
```

Are you sure you're calling the right `sqlite3` program once it's installed? SQLite is a "keg-only" formula; that is, unlike most homebrew formulas, it does not get linked in to /usr/local/bin, to avoid conflicting with the `sqlite` supplied with OS X. You need to call the homebrew one with the full path, like `/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.7.16.2/bin/sqlite3`.

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.7.16.2/bin/sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.16.2 2013-04-12 11:52:43
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select soundex('Hello, world!');
H464
```

It would be easy to add a --with-soundex option to the main homebrew `sqlite` formula, so you don't have to maintain a separate formula. If you think enough people would use it, head on over to [the Homebrew issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues) and put in a request for it.